# Detect and process only unique images

Tags: c#, data-structures, duplicates

The problem I'm having is that I have an image that appears on two pages in the same book.

I wish my program to react (trigger a side-effect) only when encountering new images and ignore duplicates.Once it has done that I want it to reset so the process is repeated.

```
namespace testpad
{
    class Interaction: Scene
    {
        public override string Name => "Interaction";

        public static RectMap imageone = new RectMap()
        {
            X = 239,
            Y = 199,
            Width = 125,
            Height = 18
        };
        public static RectMap imagetwo = new RectMap()
        {
            X = 217,
            Y = 317,
            Width = 428,
            Height = 12

        public override bool Match(ScriptBase script)
        {
            return script.Match(imageone, 90),
                      || script.Match(imagetwo, 90);

        }
        public override void OnMatched(ScriptBase script)
        {
            if (script.Match(imageone, 90))
            {
                script.PressKey() { A = true });
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            else if (script.Match(imagetwo, 90))
            {
                script.Press() { B = true });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could store your image identifier in a `Hashset` at first pass and then just check if it exists.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Image identifier as in "Imageone" "imagetwo"?, I've never used a hashset before. The images I'm using have been hashed but I left that out of the posted code for size reasons. So in the Hashset do the hashes disappear after they have been processed or detected?.

Comment: You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) .Basically all you need is to give all your images a unique id , pass through your records and try to add them in the hashset.Your adding operation would either fail ( if record exist) or not.

Comment: So, um, what is `ScriptBase`? `RectMap`? `Scene`? Where do these classes come from and what do they do? And, what kind of content are you processing? From your question, it could be anything from url references in html pages to fuzzy matches on scanned images. Code posted here should be compilable to reproduce the problem, but as it is, your _problem_ is not even clear.

Comment: @Nyerguds Sorry I should have mentioned its from a github library https://github.com/komefai/PS4Macro

Comment: That's only half of my question, though. You still haven't explained what kind of content you're actually handling. And, uh, linking to the code of an "Automation utility for PS4 Remote Play" raises more questions than it answers, when your question seems to be about "pages in a book".

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian The hashset solution worked perfect thanks mate.

Comment: @Nyerguds, Sorry Nyerduds you were beaten to it by Bercovici for a solution. :)

Comment: @baggypants71 : If the solution solved your problem please don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: @baggypants71 I'm not trying to "beat" anyone. All I was aiming to do was make you edit your question to clarify what you were actually trying to ask. It seems a lot of the confusion here was caused by someone editing your question and adding the completely inaccurate "image processing" tag to it... though this inaccuracy was still ultimately caused by your own vague question phrasing. In fact, you _still_ didn't explain what kind of data you're processing here; "book" and "page" are concepts which have no meaning in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect a collection of objects and you want to take actions based upon their frequency of apparition the best solution would be a `Dictionary<[Key],int>` where the `Key` is the identifier (in your case a `String` with the name of the image) and the  value represents the frequency of your key.Whenever you encounter an object (in your case  lets call it `image`)with a given `Key` you increment the value stored at that key.Afterwards you can take decisions based upon resulting frequencies.

However in your case you just need to react only `once` , the first time you encounter a new image , so a `HashSet<String>`  would be your best bet.

So your code would look like:

```
public void Iterate(IEnumerable<(string,object)>images)
{
     HashSet<string>set=new HashSet<string>();
     foreach(var item in images)
     {
         if(!set.TryGetValue(item.item1,out object obj))
         {
             set.Add(item.item1);
             //React(item.item2) ---do something the first time you encounter the image 
         }
     }

}
```